# What are the Optimal Projects to Take Advantage of a Pocket Dimension with Variable Time?

Tags: science-based, time, universe

Greetings from the University of Scienceton!

We're very excited to announce the recent discovery (or creation) of a pocket universe where the flow of time varies dramatically as one gets farther into and into the pocket universe.

Just on the other side of the edge of the membrane separating our universe and the pocket one, time flows at much the same rate, but the farther one goes (the distances seem to vary) time flows faster and faster.

As such, we're looking for research projects ideas that would take advantage of this chrono-spatial phenomenon, specifically, projects that would benefit from the 2x as fast, 5x as fast, 10x as fast, 100x as fast, and 1,000x as fast zones of time.

One we're already working on (for example) is Stanford's Folind@Home protein folding project.

Thanks for your help.
Onward!

Comment: How big is the pocket? Is it possible to build structures from the surface trough the different time-speed regions to the depth?

Comment: Hey b.Lorenz, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you rephrase it? (To answer at least part of your question, the pocket has a surface area of ~200 million square miles, though not all of it is accessible, thanks to various space-time anomalies.)

Comment: Do you mean 1000x faster than time on Earth? As in, 1000 days in the Pocket Universe is 1 day on Earth?

Comment: I suppose that the surface of the pocket is in the space. (since 200 million mile**2 is huge ) But what are the inner dimensions: is it an infinite universe, just touching ours on dis surface, or only has the volume of a 200 mile**2 surface sphere? My second question concerns a building (or space station), which has parts in our universe, crosses the membrane, and goes in the fast time region. Would this remain intact? If not, I have to use autonomous probes for everything I want to send into the pocket.

Comment: How much get time faster if I sink one meter in the pocket? (If it is nonlinear, please state explicitly the timespeed(depth) function.) This matters, because some projects could make use of the difference between two timespeeds.

Comment: -Garto: That's correct!

-b.Lorenz: So the way I imagine it currently, there's a 10 ft x 10 ft x 10 ft portal from our world to this pocket dimension. The other side of the portal is a flat cone (with an impermeable surface, so you can't dig "down") that extends outwards and upwards.

As for the rate of the time/change, one of the tricky parts of the dimension is that it's variable. In some sections, a 10-meter move forward equates to a 1.01x increase, while in other sections, it's an a 10x increase. Generally though, the farther you go, the greater the increase vs Earth-time.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd: Prudence](https://xkcd.com/665/).

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it proposes a setup and asks for open-ended ways to exploit it. This seems, to me, to be idea generation, which is generally considered to be too broad a question for this site. A better question might be to propose your own ideas on how to use the pocket dimension, then to ask if those things are realistic. I am voting to close as 'too broad.'

Comment: @kingledion Exactly what is being debated now in meta... :-) http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/putting-opinion-based-questions-on-hold-too-fast

Comment: Good to know, @kingledion and @SRM! Frankly, the types of questions I'm interested in asking are primarily opinion-based (which I feel like suits this stackexchange, if not the others), so it would be nice to have a tag along those lines.

I love the SE style of voting, reputation, etc. but many of my questions get put on hold for being too broad, which is sad.

Comment: Interesting question, but basically answer is trivial everything which takes time can benefit from that. As for manufacturing things it will open way for good but slow (and because of that not used) set of technologies. Easy and fast regulation of production amounts. Kinda semi related )) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqEgMLDS5CM (not the best fragment of the story, rick and morty and battery world). But yes, examples of implications can be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Rent it to whiskey makers. They can age the barrels artificially and find out what is the true optimal age of a whiskey. 40 years, 60 years, 100 years? Finally the liquor enthusiasts will find out at what point it stops getting better, or even if it does...

Comment: This would be great not just for investigation - but also for actual production runs of whiskey or even some wines!

Comment: And cheeses, and jerky, and leathers...

Answer (score 3):

Right off the top of my head I can think of a few possibilities

1. Send a piece of handcrafted material through into the 1000 to 1 area - and age it quickly. EG A brand new "Antique" of some kind.   Then when brought back - it can be tested and it's age "authenticated"
2. With such a large area - you could send through a small planetoid with some selfsustaining terraforming processes in place.  Once you bring it back - it would then be ready for Colonisation - so locate it in one of the Lagrange points - and you have a LOT of private real estate
3. A Prison for horrific criminals where you can very quickly have them live out their entire lifespan and die of natural causes
4. Scientific experiments. Loads of them. Mostly based around the science of gerontology.  You could send through caged rats/ mice that you believe you have treated to live a long time EG [Do Buckyballs Extend Lifespan?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/lyle-j-dennis-md/buckminsterfullerene_b_1449974.htm) and very quickly get the answers...